# How to pass onTap Function to ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

My Drawer Content:

```
drawer: Drawer(
    elevation: 0.0,
    child: Container(
      color: kBackgroundColor,
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey,
              image: DecorationImage(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                image: AssetImage('images/banner.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('App Test'),
          ),
          ReusableOptionTile(
            textData: 'Home',
            icon: Icons.home,
            onTouch: () {
              print('Home Clicked');
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ),
),
```

Extracted List Tile Content:

```
    class ReusableOptionTile extends StatelessWidget {
 const ReusableOptionTile(
      {required this.icon, required this.textData, required this.onTouch});
  final IconData icon;
  final String textData;
  final Function onTouch;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5.0,
          ),
          Text('$textData'),
        ],
      ),
    onTap: onTouch,   // ERROR POINT
    );
  }
}
```

I Extracted the List Tile from Drawer for making the code more reusable but now unable to pass the on tap function for different tile.
at error point  it is show error "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'."

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try changing the type of onTouch to 'void Function()?'?

Comment: Thanks Arun, but now the error "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end." at call point(from drawer) of this card.

Comment: You have to call onTouch in ReusableOptionTile. ```onTap: onTouch()```. Check Len_X's answer for the full structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onTouch` should be extracted as a void function

```
void onTouch(){
 print('Home Clicked');
 Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

then

```
ReusableOptionTile(
            textData: 'Home',
            icon: Icons.home,
            onTouch: onTouch,
          ),
```

and called

```
ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5.0,
          ),
          Text('$textData'),
        ],
      ),
    onTap: onTouch(),
    );
```